# Referencing an object of a model with all foreign keys in Django admin UI

Tags: python, mysql, django

I am developing my Djnago app for processing data into DB from admin frontend. 
I have a table with both foreign keys in it.

`class exam_questions(models.Model):
    exam_id=models.ForeignKey(exams, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    question_id=models.ForeignKey(questions, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    def __int__(self):
        return self.exam_id`

When I am trying to return the above field it is shown in admin UI as exam_questions object for all values added into table. 
Is there a way to get the actual value of the column displayed in admin UI.

I have other tables which have different definitions and I am able to display the required field from that. The issue is observed only when all keys in model are foreign keys

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide the `__str__` or `__unicode__` functions, with regard to your python version, in a model for Django admin to be able to list items with their proper intended information.

```
@python_2_unicode_compatible
class exam_questions(models.Model):
    exam_id=models.ForeignKey(exams, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    question_id=models.ForeignKey(questions, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __int__(self):
        return self.exam_id

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s - %s' % (self.exam_id.name, self.question_id.name)
```

If you're coding with cross version compatibility, you need to decorate your model with `@python_2_unicode_compatible`, and only override the `__str__` method.

Anyways but, why your `ForeignKeys` have *_id* in them ? Django automatically adds the *_id* to FKs that points to the id of the related instance.

Comment: yes..on the actual database i got it like question_id_id. for using the db table in other application, it should be like question_id only, any way to get rid of that extra param similar to how we override tablenames in meta class?

Comment: What parameter ? You mean the *_id* postfix ? just remove the *_id*s from your model definitions and make a new migration.